# Going crazy because of pip install and packages

Tags: python, module, pip, package

Currently trying to install hyperopt/optuna for the last 6 hours. Sorry If this question got already asked a 100 times but I cant find a solution that helps.
Running Python 3.8.0 but I have python 3.9 installed aswell which I guess is the root of my problem.

`pip install hyperopt` installs but then I get the Module not found error, so I checked where it is installed.

`pip install hyperopt`

> Requirement already satisfied: hyperopt in c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.2.7)

All suggestions I found didnt work.

`python3.8 -m pip install hyperopt`

> The term 'python3.8' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...

I updated pip install now it tells me this.

`pip -V`

> pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

I tried a lot more obviously but I cant even remember everything I did

Answer (score -1):

I Dont know how but the modules name just turned green and it works. I did absolutely nothing, no clue what happened.

Comment: This suites more of as a comment rather than a answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).